# Final token for access to the Google Analytics API, which does not expire

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, access-token

How to create a token that does not expire for use in function?

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({serverAuth: {access_token: XXXX }});
```

I am using the javascript language. I need an ajax function or jquery.post return this token.

Thank you!!

Comment: It is not possible to create an access token which does not expire. Please see [Using OAuth to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for details. Is there a reason why you cannot use the standard auth models? Do you need offline access? why not use a refresh token?

Comment: I needed access the User does not need to log in to the Google button, after having read the documentation that you gave me saw that I can create a server-side service that provides me a valid token. Thanks for the info and availability.